# Tabbar in ios at the top of screen

Tags: android, ios, swift

I want to make tabbar at the top of the screen in iOS and want to place 3-4 tabs. Android is giving functionality by default using Tab bar layout. For more understanding https://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)

Comment: I want a custom solution. The library can be a risk.

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: My application will be a brand app like Instagram. That's why I'm thinking for a custom solution. BTW thanks

Comment: You can try UISegmentedControl: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) inside your ViewController. Create a custom tab bar on your ViewController and set actions for each bar to navigate the pages on your UICollectionView.

You can manipulate your Custom [UICollectionViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell) inside [cellForItemAt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618029-collectionview) to differentiate each page.

For UICollectionView tutorial you can check out this page: https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started

I have created a view pager with a bottom tab bar, like instagram has, on one of my apps using this UICollectionView.